# Trying to read a ieee file created by wgrid with fortran. I get weird entries

Tags: binary, fortran, ieee

I am trying to read a binary ieee file created by wgrib. I have a bunch of GRIB files from the ECMWF center, and I convert them to binary ieee. I am trying to read it with fortran, but there is no way I am able to get the right values (huge values for number of rows (Nlon) and columns (Nlat) of the grid). Here are the commands I use to create the ieee file from dos line:

```
 'wgrib C:\gribs\IGD01211200012112001 -d 6 -ieee -big_endian IGD01211200012112001.bin
```

And these are the fortran commands

```
 open(12,file='IGD01211200012112001.bin',form='binary',status='old')
 read(12) Nlon
 read(12) Nlat
```

I also tried

```
 open(12,file='IGD01211200012112001.bin',access='stream')
```

but nothing changed. No improvement using 
     open(12,file='IGD01211200012112001.bin',form='unformatted',status='old')
but if well remember the latter uses some padding on left and right of values.

I tried also to play with the options  -little_endian or -big_endian both nothing changes. Any suggestion? I also tried to save it as bin, with the flag -bin instead of -ieee but nothing changed. In the wrib website ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib/grib2ieee.txt not much is said. Something is said here for wgrib2 http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/ieee.html but it does not help much.
thanks
A.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at [http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/bin_ieee_text_format.html](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/index.html) the file being written is not what you are expecting it to be.  For `bin` or `ieee` output you will get data in either of the following formats:

> ```
> Binary and IEEE, no header
>
> (grid 1)  (binary float value)        grid value
>           (binary float value)
>           ...
>           (binary float value)        nx*ny values
>
> (grid 2)  (binary float value)
>           (binary float value)
>           ...
>           (binary float value)        nx*ny values
>   
> etc
> ```

or

> ```
> Binary and IEEE, with header
>
> (grid 1)  (binary integer)    nx*ny*sizeof(float)
>           (binary float value)
>           ...
>           (binary float value)    nx*ny values
>           (binary integer)    nx*ny*sizeof(float)
>
> (grid 2)  (binary integer)    nx*ny*sizeof(float)
>           (binary float value)
>           ...
>           (binary float value)    nx*ny values
>           (binary integer)    nx*ny*sizeof(float)
> ```

You are attempting to read dimension lengths before the grid, but this only works if you specify the `-text` output option instead of a binary or ieee format.